# How to add my custom page resolver instead of Spartacus page resolver?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm adding my resolver (which extended from PageMetaResolver) into providers in my own home.module. However, my method 'resolve' is not called. Have you got any ideas?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomePageMetaResolver extends PageMetaResolver implements PageDescriptionResolver {

  constructor(
    protected routingService: RoutingService,
    protected translationService: TranslationService,
    protected cms: CmsService
  ) {
    super();
    this.pageType = PageType.CONTENT_PAGE;
  }

  resolve(): Observable<PageMeta> {
    console.log('RESOLVE')

    return this.cms.getCurrentPage().pipe(
      switchMap(page =>
        combineLatest([
          this.resolveDescription()
        ])
      ),
      map(([description]) => ({ description }))
    );
  }

  resolveDescription(): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(sub => {
      sub.next('test description');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

Please specify not only `this.pageType`, but also `this.pageTemplate` for your `PageMetaResolver`.

---

### Detailed explanation

#### The most specific Page Meta Resolver wins

Guessing from the name of your meta resolver, you want to provide custom meta only for your Home page. Please note that **the most specific meta resolver wins** thanks to the simple scoring algorithm, which takes into consideration 2 factors: *page type* and *page template* (see source https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/blob/develop/projects/core/src/cms/page/page-meta.resolver.ts#L11).

Currently your resolver `HomePageMetaResolver` has the same specificity as the generic one so your `resolve` method is not called.

[image: specificity of all Page Meta Resolvers]

You need to specify more your meta resolver by defining its property `this.pageTemplate = '<name-of-page-template-used-only-at-homepage>'`. Then your `HomePageMetaResolver` will get higher score than a default `ContentPageMetaResolver` whenever you visit a homepage.

#### Custom scoring algorithms

For custom scoring algorithms (which could take `pageId` into account, for instance), you can overwrite the method `getScore` of your `PageMetaResolver`s. You can even extend the method `PageMetaService.getMetaResolver` to redefine all rules of chosing the right page meta resolver. But for your case the standard solution (described above) should suffice.